# android integrating stripe to my firebase app

Tags: android, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe to my firebase app. I have been following [this tutorial from the stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder?platform=android&lang=node&client=javaclient)
I try to run my app to see if everything works, but I see a pop up message before I type my card information saying

> Error:Response(protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=https:myappnamehere-ee39b.firebaseio.com/create-payment-intent)

then when I attempt to ignore this message and type in my card information anyway and I proceed to click the pay button my app crashes and I get these errors and I'm not really sure what its telling me to do. Can I please get some help this is my first time trying to integrate stripe into my firebase app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.ddoo, PID: 29165
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter clientSecret
    at com.stripe.android.model.ConfirmPaymentIntentParams$Companion.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(Unknown Source:29)
    at com.stripe.android.model.ConfirmPaymentIntentParams$Companion.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams$default(ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.kt:420)
    at com.stripe.android.model.ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(Unknown Source:14)
    at com.myapp.ddoo.PaymentPageActivity.lambda$startCheckout$0$PaymentPageActivity(PaymentPageActivity.java:103)
    at com.myapp.ddoo.-$$Lambda$PaymentPageActivity$lysPf2qYJjjVdPRqihuLblLplpI.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6308)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24949)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6615)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)`
```

I have my code here for you to take a look maybe you will see something I don't

```
private static final String BACKEND_URL = "https://myappnamehere-ee39b.firebaseio.com/";
    private OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    private String paymentIntentClientSecret;
    private Stripe stripe;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_page);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
        // Configure the SDK with your Stripe publishable key so it can make requests to Stripe
        stripe = new Stripe(
                getApplicationContext(),
                Objects.requireNonNull("pk_test_51GzvqSI4qFEpgfxS15GlPnxcrL4Sb5CZsv5AWXGPW1ihpQBTB9OPSh9nnZxY2zY71bVacdmJQ4gRxKYmCw3SCVQo00KUZF8psk")
        );
          startCheckout();


    }

    private void startCheckout(){
        // Create a PaymentIntent by calling the server's endpoint.
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        String json = "";
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json, mediaType);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BACKEND_URL + "create-payment-intent")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        httpClient.newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new PayCallback(PaymentPageActivity.this));


        // Hook up the pay button to the card widget and stripe instance
        Button payButton = findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        payButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            CardInputWidget cardInputWidget = findViewById(R.id.cardInputWidget);
            PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
            if (params != null) {
                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                        .createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, paymentIntentClientSecret);
                stripe.confirmPayment(PaymentPageActivity.this, confirmParams);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayAlert(@NonNull String title,
                              @Nullable String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        builder.create().show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Handle the result of stripe.confirmPayment
        stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data, new PaymentResultCallback(this));
    }
    private void onPaymentSuccess(@NonNull final Response response) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, String> responseMap = gson.fromJson(
                Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string(),
                type
        );
        paymentIntentClientSecret = responseMap.get("clientSecret");
    }
    private static final class PayCallback implements Callback {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<PaymentPageActivity> activityRef;
        PayCallback(@NonNull PaymentPageActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
                    Toast.makeText(
                            activity, "Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
            );
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull final Response response)
                throws IOException {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
                        Toast.makeText(
                                activity, "Error: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                );
            } else {
                activity.onPaymentSuccess(response);
            }
        }
    }
    private static final class PaymentResultCallback
            implements ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<PaymentPageActivity> activityRef;
        PaymentResultCallback(@NonNull PaymentPageActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentIntentResult result) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            PaymentIntent paymentIntent = result.getIntent();
            PaymentIntent.Status status = paymentIntent.getStatus();
            if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                // Payment completed successfully
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                activity.displayAlert(
                        "Payment completed",
                        gson.toJson(paymentIntent)
                );
            } else if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                // Payment failed – allow retrying using a different payment method
                activity.displayAlert(
                        "Payment failed",
                        Objects.requireNonNull(paymentIntent.getLastPaymentError()).getMessage()
                );
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            // Payment request failed – allow retrying using the same payment method
            activity.displayAlert("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

While I doubt it's the cause of the error message, one mistake I see in your code is the URL that you post to. You're trying to access the Firebase Realtime Database though its REST API, which means that URLs must end with `.json`. So your `.url(BACKEND_URL + "create-payment-intent")` will not work and should be:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(BACKEND_URL + "create-payment-intent.json")
        .post(body)
        .build();
```

Comment: I just corrected that part  now I get error pop up message bade request  url=https://myappname-ee39b.firebaseio.com/create-payment-intent.json